# How do I alter behaviour of jQuery .mouseleave() based on the element the cursor moves *to*?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi guys I have put together a simple dropdown menu system that uses hoverIntent to display the submenu and also display a lightbox style 'lights out' dark background.

I've got the menu working, but I'd like to update it so if you move from one item to the next the dark background stays where it is rather than disappearing and reappearing.

I have created a jsFiddle so you can see what I'm talking about:
http://jsfiddle.net/gGd6Y/10/

Try hovering over menu item 1 then moving to item 2.

I would like to be able to see the element the mouse cursor has moved to in the .mouseleave() part of the call to HoverIntent, then if it's another menu item I would prevent the dark background from being switched off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the way the HTML is currently setup it can't be done. The shadow covers the other hoverable elements. So when you `mouseleave` you are hovering over the shadow not the other LIs.

My proposed solution: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/k98LP/

I made the menu appear above the shadow. I delayed the shadow fade out action and made sure no other menu item was hovered before actually fading out.

Comment: This is the main issue.  There is no mouseenter on the other menu items while the shadow is displayed because it's on top of them so blocking the mouse events to them.

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/gGd6Y/11/

I've changed the menu items to stay on top of the overlay.

**Edit:**

Solution proposed in my last comment:

http://jsfiddle.net/gGd6Y/16/

Comment: +1 I like how you attached the shadow fade out action to the menu. Stealing now.

Comment: Another good answer, thanks. The unhovered menu items are now no longer covered by the shadow, which the design requires. I'll see if I can achieve a similar effect by adding some background to them.

Comment: An alternative would be to add a "mini overlay" to each menu item, so you can show them when you show the overlay and retain the mouse capture on the menu items.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to add mouseleave listener to container of all items.

More flexible solution is to store boolean values `is_element_hovered` for each element. When mouseleave event happens, set small delay and after that delay check your boolean values and set background animation properly.

Comment: I've "zerovoted" you because this can be used if worked out a little, but it's too much effort for an easy thing.

Comment: The issue is that the shadow background is over the top of the navbar so there is no mouseenter on the navbar when the shadow is displaying.  One cannot fix this until that is fixed.